# Error: PDFDocument: stream must have data

Tags: node.js, pdf, hapi.js, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js to parse pdf files. First I am uploading the file and then trying to parse that file.I am passing the url to parse function to read it in PDFJS.getDocument(url)

If I don't use the upload part and hardcode the URL of the pdf file it works.

Code :

```
var parse = function(payload,callback){
            var data = payload;
            if(data.file){
                var name = data.file.hapi.filename;
                var ext = name.split('.');
                var extension = ext[1];
                if(extension == "pdf"){
                    var path = __dirname + "/uploads/" + name;
                    checkFileExist();
                    var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
                    file.on('error', function (err) { 
                        console.error(err) 
                    });
                    data.file.pipe(file);
                    var fileName = data.file.hapi.filename;
                    console.log(fileName);
                    var fileAbsolutepath = __dirname + "/uploads/" + fileName ;
                    console.log(fileAbsolutepath);
                    var parser = script.pdfParser(fileAbsolutepath,function(err,resp){
                        if(err){
                            callback(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            callback(resp);
                        }
                    })
                    callback(JSON.stringify(fileName));
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Invalid fileType");
                    callback(JSON.stringify("Invalid FileType"));
                }  
            }
}

var checkFileExist = function() {
    var path = __dirname + '/uploads';
    fs.exists(path, function(exists) {
        if (exists === false) fs.mkdirSync(path);
    });
};


exports.pdfParser = function(url,callback){
PDFJS.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';

PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function (pdf) {
    var pdfDocument = pdf;
}}
```

The file is uploaded properly with expected file size in uploads folder still I get error : "Error: PDFDocument: stream must have data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse files with pdf.js, rather than loading the file with PDFJS.getDocument, try converting the pdf file to an [arrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) or [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array), and use that to create a new [LocalPdfManager](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/core/pdf_manager.js) object. Then you can call the LocalPdfManager's methods directly to parse the pdf.

Something like this:

```
import { LocalPdfManager } from 'pdfjs-dist/lib/core/pdf_manager';

pdfManager = new LocalPdfManager(1, arrayBuffer, '', {}, '');
// parameters = (docId, data, password, evaluatorOptions, docBaseUrl)
pdfManager.ensureDoc('parseStartXRef', []); // [] = arguments
pdfManager.ensureDoc('parse', false); // false = recoveryMode
pdfManager.ensureDoc('numPages');
pdfManager.ensureDoc('fingerprint');
```

Then look at `pdfManager.pdfDocument` for the parsed pdf data.

For example, the main "/Catalog" entry will be in `pdfManager.pdfDocument.catalog.catDict`.

I've used this method to successfully parse and modify pdf files locally in a browser. I haven't tried it on a server with node.js, but I expect it should work the same.